# A function for non-linear animation steps (large in the middle, small at the ends)

Tags: exponential-function, interpolation

In a word game for Android I animate movement of letter tiles (for example when user selects "shuffle tiles" or "return tiles from game board" in menu) in a **linear** way (they have constant velocities) by the algorithm explained below -

[image: android app screenshot]

**The current algorithm:**

- The current coordinates of a letter tile are: `mRect.top` and `mRect.left`
- The end destination coordinates are: `mTarget.x` and `mTarget.y`
- As long as there are moving tiles, the app screen is redrawn every 30 milliseconds.

When a tile should be moved somewhere in an animated way, the following method calculates the distance and divides it in 8 **equal** steps:

```
public void startAnimatedMove(float x, float y) {
    mTarget.x = x;
    mTarget.y = y;
    steps = 8;
    mStepX = (mTarget.x - mRect.left) / steps;
    mStepY = (mTarget.y - mRect.top) / steps;
}
```

And then when the next 30 milliseconds passed, the tile is moved and drawn in the new position (the last step is special - so that the tile is put exactly at `mTarget.x` and `mTarget.y`):

```
private void nextStep() {
    if (--steps == 0)
        moveTo(mTarget.x, mTarget.y);
    else 
        moveTo(mRect.left + mStepX, mRect.top + mStepY);
}
```

This works well, but the tiles move with constant velocity, because the `mStepX` and `mStepY` are always same distance (represented by red line in the above diagram).

**My question:**

I would like to change the steps, so that they are small at the start and end of movement - and large in the middle. I.e. I'd like to have a function for "easying in and out".

I think this way movement will look more natural and I think I probably need an `x^2` or `sin` based functions (represented by green line in above diagram), which I would call here:

```
private void nextStep() {
    if (--steps == 0)
        moveTo(mTarget.x, mTarget.y);
    else 
        moveTo(mRect.left + calcStepX(steps), mRect.top + calcStepY(steps));
}
```

Please give me some recommendations for such a function (input: step number 0 to 7, output: distance in pixels to move along x- or y-axis), as I am struggling with math here.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have ended using [Easing Equations by Robert Penner](http://robertpenner.com/easing/).

The [jQuery implementation](https://github.com/danro/jquery-easing/blob/master/jquery.easing.js) source code have been most easy to read for me.

Trying them out has been comfortable [at this Flash app](http://gizma.com/easing/).